# How to isolate web console of network switch from LAN where they working

Tags: network

Network switches on my work have web console. Despite it is password protected I want to hide it from LAN. Currently switches has static IP with mask that differ from DHCP server, so they not visible from PC that get it's IP from DHCP. Is there any better approach to prevent access from non-authorized PC to switches web console?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an option to limit who has access to the web console by IP address, or by MAC address, you could limit the access to only the admin workstations. It would be even better to limit access not only to the web console, but to the IP of the switch (if there is such option), so that it is not easily detectable with network scanners.